# Adding the .attr() to a variable - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am using Rickshaw framework which uses D3 for visualization.. I am creating a variable node where I am appending the Rectangle. I want Padding to be 20 whenever it satisfies a particular condition.

```
 var nodes = graph.vis.selectAll("path").data(series.stack.filter(function(d) {
                    return d.y !== null
                })).enter().append("svg:rect").attr("x", function(d) {
   console.log(brandCount[v])
    if(d.x == brandCount[v]) {
        console.log("called2")
        v++;

        var z = 0;
        padding = 10;
    } else {
        padding = 0;
    }.attr("y", function(d) {
                    return (graph.y(d.y0 + Math.abs(d.y))) * (d.y < 0 ? -1 : 1 )
                }).attr("width", 30).attr("height", function(d) {
                    return graph.y.magnitude(Math.abs(d.y))
                }).attr("rx", 4).attr("transform", transform);
```

What should I do here to access and add an attribute to the variable?

Brand count, array has many values`([1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 5, 8, 4, 1, 6, 3, 1, 9, 1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 1, 1, 2, 6, 1, 6, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 1])`. After every values I need a space. I just tried to loop it.. as brand_count[v] and increasing it by v++.

Answer (score 1):

You need to evaluate your condition inside the function that sets the `x` attribute, i.e.

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
    if(z == brand_Count[v]) {
        v++;
        z = 0;
        padding = 10;
    } else {
        padding = 0;
    }
    return graph.x(d.x) + padding;
}
```

For adding padding after 5 values, you don't need a separate counter:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return graph.x(d.x) + (Math.floor(i/5)*20);
}
```

For adding padding after specific values, you can do something like this:

```
var counter = 0;
// ...more code...
.attr("x", function(d) {
    if(d == 1 || d == 4) counter++;
    return graph.x(d.x) + (counter*20);
}
```

If the values are stored in an array:

```
var counter = 0, brandCount = [1,2,3];
// ...more code...
.attr("x", function(d) {
    if(brandCount.indexOf(d) != -1) counter++;
    return graph.x(d.x) + (counter*20);
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much.. It`s the procedure for adding the Padding right? I am not getting space after the co-ordinate...

Comment: I've just taken your code and made it work. If you explain more clearly what you want, I might be able to help you with that.

Comment: The problem here is that I need a space after every 1,4,1....  Not just for 1,4 and 1.. Any idea to handle that Lars?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Do you mean that you need space if the preceding elements are `[1,4,1]` or that you want a space after `1` and after `4`?

Comment: Yeah I meant the latter one. I need space after 1, after 4, after1, after4................ Possible?

Comment: checked the updated answer.. Thank you for ur efforts.. However I need to make that dynamic.. When u check the edited question the values I am getting like 1, 4, 1, 4, 1, 6, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 6, 1, 1, 1, 6, 4,..... So after each and every value.. I need a space.. That area has to be dynamic..

Comment: I'm lost again. So you want padding after every value?

Comment: Not after every value, Lars. But after the values that is in Bar_count... For ex: if I have 1,2,4 in the bar_count.. I need a space after 1, after 2 and after 4 dynamically..